# Centralizer of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can anybody give me some hints on this? Using induction? Thanks!
For g in G, the centralizer of g is the subgroup defined as C(g) = { a in G : ag = ga }. Prove C(g) contains C(g^n).

Comment: Maybe you mean $C(g)\subseteq C(g^n)$?

Comment: The takeaway is if $x$ commutes with a set of elements, then $x$ also commutes with everything in the subgroup generated by that set.

Comment: Hint: if $x$ commutes with $g$, then $x$ commutes with $g^2$, since $xgg = gxg = ggx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, let $G$ be a finite non commutative group, there exists $n$ (the cardinal of $G$)such that $g^n=1$, so $C(g^n)=G$, but in general $C(g)$ is not $G$ for every $g$ in $G$, but $C(g)$ is contained in $C(g^n)$.

Comment: I see, thanks. The original problem is wrong. It should be "Prove C(g^n) contains C(g)".